# discord.py gives me event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'

Tags: python, discord.py

I know that this has been answered but the weird thing about my case is that it was perfectly working before I uninstalled python and pycharm and then reinstalled them. what i want to know is what i did wrong in that installation for it to give me this error. i know that this worked before because it was running in my server before i took it down to update it

apparently the line that gives the error is:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.event()<----where the error is found
async def on_ready():
    print("bot ready")
```

Comment: A decorator is usually used without parenthesis. [Documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html) shows examples without it too. Try removing it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro' discord python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71869121/typeerror-event-missing-1-required-positional-argument-coro-discord-python)

Answer (score 1):

Everything in that code should work, but the only thing you did wrong is adding the parenthesis.

So, your code should look like this:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("bot ready")
```

You're only supposed to use the parentheses for commands like `@client.command()`, but it's not like that for `@client.event`.

Please the next time you ask a question make sure you didn't do anything wrong.

If you need more help you can contact me on [Discord.py For Beginners](https://discord.gg/C8zFM3D2rn).