# TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro' discord python

Tags: python

I made this script for my discord bot:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from keep_alive import keep_alive

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '+')
bot.remove_command('help')

@bot.event()
async def on_ready():
  await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Streaming(name = "", url=""))

keep_alive()
bot.run('it is my token >:(')
```

and i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 8, in <module>
    @bot.event()
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

Then how can i fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing the problem is with your decorator.

I believe it should be just:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
   await bot.change_presence(activity = discord.Streaming(name = "", url=""))
```